# iphone:How to use ShareKit integrate in iPhone??

Tags: iphone

Hello friends,
              I want to use ShareKit integrate my iPhone Apps so please tell me any link or any idea to integrate this functionality in iPhone & how to use this kit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link for,share kit documentation http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing? [Check the official installation guide](http://getsharekit.com/install/)

Installation is pretty straightforward. Just copy the files to your project and add required frameworks, include SKH.h and that's it ;)